# Arduino - How do I stop loop and wait for next command?

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno

I want my code to halt after the first part of the code and wait unitil the switch changes state... I can't seem to find the comand to do it! Any help appreciated.
I have marked the code halfway down, where I want it to halt.

```
int switchState = 0;
void setup() {
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2,INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  switchState = digitalRead(2);
  if (switchState == LOW) {
    // The button is not pressed
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(4, LOW);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(5, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH); // green LED
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH); // red LED
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH); // red LED
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW); // green LED
    digitalWrite(4, LOW); // red LED
    digitalWrite(5, LOW); // red LED
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH); // green LED
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH); // red LED
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH); // red LED
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW); // green LED
    digitalWrite(4, LOW); // red LED
    digitalWrite(5, LOW); // red LED
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH); // green LED
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH); // red LED
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH); // red LED
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW); // green LED
    digitalWrite(4, LOW); // red LED
    digitalWrite(5, LOW); // red LED
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH); // green LED
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH); // red LED
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH); // red LED
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW); // green LED
    digitalWrite(4, LOW); // red LED
    digitalWrite(5, LOW); // red LED
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH); // green LED
    digitalWrite(4, LOW); // red LED
    digitalWrite(5, LOW); // red LED
// HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO HALT THE EXECUTION OF THE FIRST PART OF THE CODE
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(3, LOW); // green LED
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH); // red LED
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH); // red LED
    delay(250); // wait quarter of a second
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH); // red LED
    digitalWrite(5, LOW); // red LED
    delay(250); // wait quarter of a second
  }

} // go back to beginning of loo
```

I want my code to halt after the first part of the code and wait unitil the switch changes state... I can't seem to find the comand to do it! Any help appreciated.
I have marked the code halfway down, where I want it to halt.

Comment: It is a terrible idea to "stop" the main loop.  Learn how the 328P works by reading its datasheet and Application Notes and then re-think your idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with a *last state variable*:

```cpp
int switchState = 0;
int lastSwitchState = 2;

void setup() {
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2,INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  switchState = digitalRead(2);
  if (switchState != lastSwitchState) {  
    if (switchState == LOW) {
        // The button is not pressed
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
        // ...
        // HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO HALT THE EXECUTION OF THE FIRST PART OF THE CODE
        lastSwitchState = switchState;
    } else {
        // ...  
        digitalWrite(5, LOW); // red LED
        delay(250); // wait quarter of a second
        lastSwitchState = switchState;
    }
  } else {
    // Implement powersave state or idle procedure  
  }
} // go back to beginning of the loop
```

This code simply checks if the current value is equal to the last value. It only executes your core code if they are different. If they (`switchState` and `lastSwitchState`) are the same, you could enter a powersave procedure or just enter an infinite loop. So your loop "halt"s at the next iteration unless the value has changed.

Comment: That's right. No, it doesn't. The loop is an endless loop, hence I mentioned the powersave/idle mode. The loop repeats endslessly, but it ignores the main code if the state stays the same. The first google link returns [Arduino Sleep Modes and How to use them to Save the Power](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-sleep-modes-and-how-to-use-them-to-reduce-power-consumption). Pick the approach that firts best your scenario.

Comment: Okay  - The code executes, but it does not wait, it jumps straight into the next routine. I want it to cycle through it's first piece of code without looping. Then wait until a switch is pressed. Then execute the next piece of code.

Comment: There is **no** "good" wait function. You can `delay()` the execution, but waiting can at best be achieved by using some of the above mentioned sleep modes. A "wait" using an endless loop would be power-hungry and would block everything else.

Comment: So specify the events/interrupts that could unlock the "waiting" in the `else` code. This could be the _switch_ you mentioned that triggers an [interrupt](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-interrupt-tutorial-with-examples). So you can "release" the waiting by reacting to a hardware or software interrupt. This is the way to go.